# How to channel libavformat console output to custom logger?

Tags: c++, logging, ffmpeg, console, libavformat

Is there any mechanism in libavfromat to redirect its console output to a custom logging system?

E.g. I want to print output of av_dump_format with my custom logger.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I'm not sure how to formulate search query for this. I think your criticism is not reasonable - even if topic in question is described in detail in documentation, I still think it is useful to have a proper answer to this question at stackoverflow for many reasons:
- google will most likely give you refernce to stackoverflow than to libavformat docs
- it is not always obvious how to formulate a search query (my case)
- presence of information on something at stack overflow makes it more attractive to new people

Answer (score 0):

See: https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/6.0/group__lavu__log.html#ga14034761faf581a8b9ed6ef19b313708

```c
static void callback(void * avcl, int level, const char * fmt, va_list va)
{
}

av_log_set_callback(callback);
```

Answer (score -1):

FFmpeg prints the log output to stderr, and since stderr is a FILE, you can open a pipe to it and read. Something like this:

```
// Input and output pipe
int pipes[2];
pipe(pipes);
dup2(pipes[1], STDERR_FILENO);
// Close the output pipe, we're not writing to it
close(pipes[1]);
// Open the input pipe so we can read from it
FILE* inputFile = fdopen(pipes[0], "r");
char readBuffer[256];

// Create a new thread and do this
while (1) {
    fgets(readBuffer, sizeof(readBuffer), inputFile);

    // Do whatever you want with readBuffer here
    std::cout << readBuffer << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: libav actually has an interface to allow hooking it's output, your suggestion is like using a sledge hammer to put in a nail. As soon as I recall the details I will post it here as an answer.